# How to replace image URL when upload image in Froala editor?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, froala

I've tried to upload image to my own server(Firebase). I managed to upload to my server by using this event.

```
'froalaEditor.image.beforeUpload' : function(e, editor, images) {
     let uploadTask: firebase.storage.UploadTask;
     var time = Date.now()
     let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
     let path = `this.uid/Article_img/${time}`;
     uploadTask = storageRef.child(path).put(images[0])
     uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
     (error) => {
        console.log(error)
     },
     () => {
        this.downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
     })
}
```

When I inserted the image, image was uploaded to my server successfully. But, I don't know how to replace the url in the editor because now it still use default url. I have no idea how to replace or change image URL.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: can you please tell how you resolved this issue?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Check this github issue: https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a bit of experiment.

What I did was

var returnFileUpload = FroalaEditor.Image.Upload(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, uploadPath);

and then instead of returning the link the above method returned I changed the link that pointed to the right directory in my server. I had to append a few path links to the above returned link.
Something like

var tempLinkCreatedByEditor = returnFileUpload.ToString();

var finalLinkToBeReturned = "/../goBackOneLevelUpinDirectory/" + tempLinkCreatedByEditor.Substring(10);

Hope this helps.